# Contact form javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php

First of all, I'm new to website creation and especially to php.

I have created a contact form for my website with a validation and a message that is displayed if everything is filled in correctly (see the snippet below). I know that the validation has to be done on both the client and server side, but I know that I am dealing with something else.

I have created a php file that works: I get the email when the user clicks submit.

I am faced with two things.

1. How do I keep the javascript validation and the message on the front end?
2. How do I configure the php to stay on the page, or better yet, run in the back and only submit the form to my email?

```
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  
  
  $mailto = "contact@statsmap.ch"; //Send the email to this adress
  
  //All the inputs informations
  $mailfrom = $_POST['email'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  //$message = "NAME: " .$name. "\r\n\n". "Wrote the following Message:" ."\r\n". $_POST['message'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $headers = "From: ". $mailfrom; 
  $sendMail = mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send mail to website owner
  


}

?>
```

```js
const form = document.getElementById('formContact');
const nameContact = document.getElementById('name');
const emailContact = document.getElementById('email');
const messageContact = document.getElementById('message');
const headerContact = document.querySelector('.headerContact')
const thankYou = document.querySelector('.Thankyou');

const isValidEmail = (email) => {
  const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
};


let isValid = true;

function checkInputs(){

  //get the values from the inputs or textarea

  const nameValue = nameContact.value.trim();
  const emailValue = emailContact.value.trim();
  const messageValue = messageContact.value.trim();

  if (nameValue === ''){
    //show error
    //add error class
    setErrorFor(nameContact, 'Name cannot be blank');
  } else{
    //add success class
    setSuccesFor(nameContact);
  }

  if (emailValue === ''){
    //show error
    //add error class
    setErrorFor(emailContact, 'Email cannot be blank');
  } else if(!isValidEmail(emailValue)){
    setErrorFor(emailContact, 'Please add a valid email adress');
  } else{
    setSuccesFor(emailContact);
  }

  if (messageValue === ''){
    //show error
    //add error class
    setErrorFor(messageContact, 'Message cannot be blank');
  } else if (messageValue.length < 20){
    setErrorFor(messageContact, 'Message need to be at least 20 characters');
  }
  else{
    //add success class
    setSuccesFor(messageContact);
  }

}

function setErrorFor(input, message){
  isValid=false;
  const formControl = input.parentElement; 
  const errorContactMessage = formControl.querySelector('#Error');

  //add error message inside the span
  errorContactMessage.innerText = message;

  //add error class
  formControl.className = 'form-control error';

}

function setSuccesFor(input){

  const formControl = input.parentElement; 
  const errorContactMessage = formControl.querySelector('#Error');
  //remove message inside the span
  errorContactMessage.innerText='';

  //add success class
  formControl.className = 'form-control success';

}

let nameThk = "";
nameContact.addEventListener('input', (e) =>{
  nameThk = e.target.value;
});

form.addEventListener('submit', () =>{
  checkInputs();
  if(isValid){
    form.remove();
    headerContact.classList.add('hide');
    thankYou.classList.remove('hide');
    document.querySelector('#merci').innerHTML = `<h3>Dear ${nameThk}, thank you for reaching out ! </h3>`;
    
  }

});
```

```css
.containerContact {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  display: block;
}

.containerContact h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.form-control {
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
  position: relative;
}

.form-control input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0.025rem solid #000000;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control input::placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0.025rem solid #000000;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  color: #000000;
  resize: none;
}

.form-control textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control textarea::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control textarea::placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.form-control #textareaChecks {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
}

.form-control.success input {
  border-color: green;
}

.form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: green;
}

.form-control.error input {
  border-color: red;
}

.form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: red;
}

.form-control.success textarea {
  border-color: green;
}

.form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: green;
}

.form-control.error textarea {
  border-color: red;
}

.form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: red;
}

#Error {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#ContactSubmit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  background: #1e1e1e;
  outline: none;
  border: 0.025rem solid #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.containerThank {
  height: 300px;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
}

.containerThank h3 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
      align-self: flex-end;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.containerThank p {
  -ms-flex-item-align: start;
      align-self: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <form action="/php/contactMail.php" method="POST" class="formContact" id="formContact" novalidate>
            <div class="form-control">
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="First and Last name">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
              <span id="Error"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
              <input type="email"  name="email" id="email" placeholder="Please enter your email">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
              <span id="Error"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
              <input type="text"  name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
              <span id="Error"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <textarea id="message" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <i id="textareaChecks" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <i id="textareaChecks" class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <span id="Error"></span>                
              </div>
              <button id="ContactSubmit" name="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <div class="Thankyou hide">
            <div class="containerThank">
            <h3 id="merci"></h3>
            <p>Our team is going to get back to you as soon as possible</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: I am interpreting your two questions to mean "How can I submit the form without reloading the page?" If this in incorrect, please add for information to your question or respond in a comment

Comment: If my understanding is correct, the answer for both questions is AJAX (search google or else for more on AJAX)

Comment: @ControlAltDel hello and thank you for your comment. I want that the php work after my javascript is passed out.  For know when i click to submit my javascript works but 1 seconds after the users goes to another page wo correspond to the php file. The best way to understand it properly is to go to my website https://statsmap.ch

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to use ajax

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you checked the variable isValid for it to be true, but you didn't provide an alternative if isValid is false.

Basically, I edited this:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{
  checkInputs();
  if(isValid){
    form.remove();
    headerContact.classList.add('hide');
    thankYou.classList.remove('hide');
    document.querySelector('#merci').innerHTML = `<h3>Dear ${nameThk}, thank you for reaching out ! </h3>`;
  } else {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
```

As you can see, if isValid is false, the script prevents the form from submitting.

Working snippet:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('formContact');
const nameContact = document.getElementById('name');
const emailContact = document.getElementById('email');
const messageContact = document.getElementById('message');
const headerContact = document.querySelector('.headerContact')
const thankYou = document.querySelector('.Thankyou');

const isValidEmail = (email) => {
  const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
};


let isValid = true;

function checkInputs(){

  //get the values from the inputs or textarea

  const nameValue = nameContact.value.trim();
  const emailValue = emailContact.value.trim();
  const messageValue = messageContact.value.trim();

  if (nameValue === ''){
    //show error
    //add error class
    setErrorFor(nameContact, 'Name cannot be blank');
  } else{
    //add success class
    setSuccesFor(nameContact);
  }

  if (emailValue === ''){
    //show error
    //add error class
    setErrorFor(emailContact, 'Email cannot be blank');
  } else if(!isValidEmail(emailValue)){
    setErrorFor(emailContact, 'Please add a valid email adress');
  } else{
    setSuccesFor(emailContact);
  }

  if (messageValue === ''){
    //show error
    //add error class
    setErrorFor(messageContact, 'Message cannot be blank');
  } else if (messageValue.length < 20){
    setErrorFor(messageContact, 'Message need to be at least 20 characters');
  }
  else{
    //add success class
    setSuccesFor(messageContact);
  }

}

function setErrorFor(input, message){
  isValid=false;
  const formControl = input.parentElement; 
  const errorContactMessage = formControl.querySelector('#Error');

  //add error message inside the span
  errorContactMessage.innerText = message;

  //add error class
  formControl.className = 'form-control error';

}

function setSuccesFor(input){

  const formControl = input.parentElement; 
  const errorContactMessage = formControl.querySelector('#Error');
  //remove message inside the span
  errorContactMessage.innerText='';

  //add success class
  formControl.className = 'form-control success';

}

let nameThk = "";
nameContact.addEventListener('input', (e) =>{
  nameThk = e.target.value;
});

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{
  checkInputs();
  if(isValid){
    form.remove();
    headerContact.classList.add('hide');
    thankYou.classList.remove('hide');
    document.querySelector('#merci').innerHTML = `<h3>Dear ${nameThk}, thank you for reaching out ! </h3>`;
  } else {
    e.preventDefault()
  }

});
```

```css
.containerContact {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  display: block;
}

.containerContact h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.form-control {
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
  position: relative;
}

.form-control input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0.025rem solid #000000;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control input::placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0.025rem solid #000000;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  color: #000000;
  resize: none;
}

.form-control textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control textarea::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control textarea::placeholder {
  color: #000000;
}

.form-control i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.form-control #textareaChecks {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
}

.form-control.success input {
  border-color: green;
}

.form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: green;
}

.form-control.error input {
  border-color: red;
}

.form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: red;
}

.form-control.success textarea {
  border-color: green;
}

.form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: green;
}

.form-control.error textarea {
  border-color: red;
}

.form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: red;
}

#Error {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#ContactSubmit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  background: #1e1e1e;
  outline: none;
  border: 0.025rem solid #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.containerThank {
  height: 300px;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
}

.containerThank h3 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
      align-self: flex-end;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.containerThank p {
  -ms-flex-item-align: start;
      align-self: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="/php/contactMail.php" method="POST" class="formContact" id="formContact" novalidate>
            <div class="form-control">
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="First and Last name">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
              <span id="Error"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
              <input type="email"  name="email" id="email" placeholder="Please enter your email">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
              <span id="Error"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
              <input type="text"  name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
              <span id="Error"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <textarea id="message" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <i id="textareaChecks" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <i id="textareaChecks" class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <span id="Error"></span>                
              </div>
              <button id="ContactSubmit" name="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <div class="Thankyou hide">
            <div class="containerThank">
            <h3 id="merci"></h3>
            <p>Our team is going to get back to you as soon as possible</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```